# Error in x[i, j] : incorrect number of dimensions :Transportation problem using Genetic Algorithm in R (GA package)

Tags: r, readxl

I am getting the following error :

> Error in x[i, j] : incorrect number of dimensions

while executing the following code :

```
library(GA)
library(readxl)

path <- "GAMS data & solution.xlsx"
c <- read_excel(path,range = "C3:G7",col_names = F)
f <- read_excel(path,range = "C10:G10",col_names = F)
d <- read_excel(path,range = "C13:G13",col_names = F)
cap <- read_excel(path,range = "C16:G16",col_names = F)
rows <- nrow(c)
cols <- ncol(c)[enter image description here][1]

val2 <-0
val1 <-0

fitness <- function(m){
    x<-m[1] 
    y<-m[2]
    
    # define fitness function
    for(i in 1:rows){
        for(j in 1:cols){
            val <- c[i,j]*x[i,j]
            val1 <- val1 + val
        }
    }
   for(i in 1:rows){
      val0 <- f[i]*y[i]
      val2 <- val2+val0
   }
    
    fitness_value <- val1 + val2
    
    #define constraint
    g1 <- x
    
    for(j in 1:cols){
    for(i in 1:rows){
        sum1 <- x[i,j]
        sum2 <- sum2+sum1
    }
        gtemp <- sum2-d[j]
        g2 <- append(g2,gtemp)
    }
    
    
        for(i in 1:rows){
            for(j in 1:cols){
            sum0 <- x[i,j]
            sum3 <- sum3+sum0
        }
        gtemp1 <- sum3-cap[i]*y[i]
        g3 <- append(g3,gtemp)
    }
    

    #penalized constraint violation
    fitness_value <- ifelse( g1 >= 0 & g2 >= 0 & g3 <= 0 , fitness_value, fitness_value + 1e5 )
    
    return(-fitness_value)
}

ga(type = "real-valued", fitness,lower = c(0,0),upper = c(10000, 1),maxiter = 1000, popSize = 100, monitor = F)
```

I am trying to solve the following problem using GA package of R:

Here is what my data looks like.

[image]

Comment: In the code shown above, you have `sum2 <- sum2+sum1`, but no initial value for `sum2`.  Same for `sum3`.

Comment: yes... forgot to initialize sum2 and sum3 outside the function where val1 and val2 are initialized. Even after this correction, still it I am getting the error.